# Nested Views in a view

Tags: eclipse, view, rcp

I want to have nested views in a single view like a JTabbedPane. Is this possible ?
If yes , please share the code or idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TabFolder control is the SWT equivalent of JTabbedPane. Here is a usage example:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#tabfolder

That SWT snippets URL is a good place to go for usage examples of SWT controls.

Comment: But for adding the tabfolder i need to code into my perspective class. I dont want to touch that class. Is there any way to do it in view only. Second thing, how can i position my views using code ?